# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).youamaAjaxLogin is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong in following code.
This is error it's showing,

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).youamaAjaxLogin is not a function

Thank you in advance.

My code is as follow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
       jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery().youamaAjaxLogin({
                redirection : '<?php echo $this->isRedirectToProfile() ?>',
                profileUrl : '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/account/',
                autoShowUp : '<?php echo $autoShowUp = (isset($_GET["yregister"])) ? "yes" : "no" ?>',
                controllerUrl : '<?php echo $this->getUrl("youama_ajaxlogin/ajax/index") ?>'
            });
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Message is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: is this a plugin `youamaAjaxLogin` ?

Comment: I have tried defining, add noconflict etc but nothing worked.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes, a magento one.

Comment: @Supal have you added jquery and the other plugin script in your page before the above script?

Comment: It seems like the plugin's js file has been included after your mentioned JS code. So it is not able to find the defined plugin function. Check in for this possibility.

Comment: @Suyog why are you using $(window).load() to initialize your plugin shouldn't it be $(document).ready()?

Comment: @Niladri good point, let me try this.

Comment: Also are you sure this is the correct way to initilize the plugin? `jQuery().youamaAjaxLogin(` instead of `jQuery.youamaAjaxLogin(`

Comment: @Niladri either way it will work.

Comment: @Suyog have you checked that whether jquery and the plugin are added in correct order in your page? that means jquery first then the plugin and then your script of initialize

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay It's happening since i minified and merged the js code.

Comment: @Niladri It's happening since i minified and merged the js code.

Comment: @Suyog what did you merge ?? check if there is any code missing

Comment: @Suyog, have you minified all the JS files separately or merged all in one js file? Which tool you used to minify ? Gulp ?

Comment: yes,i have checked nothing is missing there.